# Proving that a map is an isomorphism from an essential extension to itself.

Tags: ring-theory

I have a commutative ring $R$, and a prime ideal $P$ of $R$.  I also have a module $E$ such that $R/P$ is a submodule of $E$ and every submodule $F\neq (0)$ of $E$ satisfies $F\cap R/P\neq (0)$.
($E$ is an essential extension of $R/P$).

What I need to show:

Given an element $r\notin P$, the map:

$f:E\to E$ defined by $f(x) = rx$ is an isomorphism.

When I try to show injectivity, I assume that $f(x)  = P$. ($P$ is the $0$ element of $E_R(R/P)$.

Then $rx = P$.  Now here is my issue:  If $x\in R/P$, then I can show that $x = P$ since $r\notin P$.  But if $x\notin R/P$, all I know is that it is in $E$.  I think I need to get a contradiction somehow.

So if $x\neq 0$, I consider that $Rx\neq (0)$ is a submodule of $E$, and therefore there is a $q\neq 0$ in $R$ such that $qx\in R/P$.  Since by assumption $rx = 0$, $r(qx) = q(rx) = q(0) = 0$.

So since $qx \in R/P$, I can write $qx = x_q + P$, but this is where I am stuck (assuming I am even on the right track).  I was just blinding applying the hypothesis here and hoping things would come out the way I wanted.

Any tips on how I can show that $x= P$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in Ker(f)$. So $rx=0$.

If $x\neq 0$, by the essentiality of $R/P$,  then $Rx\cap R/P\neq 0$. This means that there is $a\in R$ with $ax\in R/P$ with $ax\neq 0$. Using the commutativity of the ring $rax=0$. So $ra\in P$. By primality of $P$, $r\in P$ or $a\in P$. By hypothesis $r\notin P$. The unique option is that $a\in P$. But as $ax\in R/P$, we have that $ax=0$.

So we conclude that  $x=0$ and $f$ is injective.